# Under remote (ssh) .. How do I remove all remotes and root logins

Tags: openssh

How do you delete ssh if you suspect ra root administrating your macbook.. And are under a control by ssh remote?

Comment: You do a complete reinstall; that is the only way to ensure that--if your were pwned--your system is completely restored.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about security or OSX, nothing Linux specific.

Comment: You mean my operating system ? Ive been doing that for 6 years... And when I get locked put with a firmware password... I take it to Apple. Ive had to reinstall twice this month at Apple. Ive done everything possible.. But I cant fix it.. And Apple refuses to do anything but reinstall. Ive recently seen my email logon mirrored... To trick me into signing in to a spoof site. Ive also caught a root administrating mu mac on logon page.. And countless guests I dont have any control over.. And so much more!

Comment: @jasonwryan: Administering ssh on Unix is pretty solidly on topic.

Comment: @user167285: ... but nothing you're saying sounds like ssh is a likely entry point.

Comment: An entry point like a backdoor?  Ive been battling almost everything under a remotes control for a long time.. Cant figure it out or get help..

Comment: @MichaelHomer the fact that SSH *may* have been the entry method (if the system is indeed compromised) matters little at this point...

Comment: Ive also identified 2 malware infections.. Some people say there isnt anything I can do.. Is this true?

Comment: @user167285 of course there is something you can do, but we cannot help you with the limited information you provide. For all we know you reuse passwords, or write them down on a piece of paper stuck under your keyboard. Or reuse your compromised ssh key-pair. What you experience is not normal, so either you did something wrong or you leave your computer in a situation where someone else can do something wrong with it. With your one line post I cannot even start to guess, but your question is IMO likely not to be relevant to the  problem.

Comment: I guess I should be asking the question I am asking the most..."Who or what can help me connect thedots

Comment: I have documented as much as I can....as things start to happen..,saved source codes/diagnostics/debuggers/ remotes/emails/phone screen shots/debuggers

Comment: Sorry about the 3 separate posts... I don't know why it did that...3 Tetra external drives... Many flash drives and memory cards.. Printer pages and source codes.  I even have a macbook ghat went into kernel panic.. That has all the content of how this evolved over 6 years... All for future documentation... Of whats happening... But now I need to consolidate material and put it together until solved and fixed. But I am not am ITT tech and need help from someone who is familiar with codes/security/and system privacy breach..... Along with online ID theft...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do you delete ssh if you suspect ra root administrating your macbook.. And are under a control by ssh remote?

Deleting (literally) `ssh` won't help.  You would need to delete / disable `sshd`.  The `ssh` command is for out-going SSH sessions.  You are dealing with incoming SSH sessions.

But deleting / disabling `sshd` isn't sufficient.  If someone has "owned" your system, then there is a good chance that they have installed other stuff that provides other ways of controlling your machine.  The only way to be sure is to do a complete reinstall of all system software and check for damage / infections in non-system software.

---

A short term workaround is disconnect from all networks.  This will at least interrupt the (supposed) hacker's active control of your system.  However, that could be tricky, given that most modern mobile systems are capable of using WiFi, etcetera, and you may not be able to control the access points that it is using.

Comment: Is there a scan for remotes and other vulnerabilities I can run.. So I can connect the dots.. And know what I need to apply fixes? Ive tried.. But obviously.. I cant run them... Im usually prevented from any of these activities. And yes... Im sure now that I have scripts implemented.. ie... configuration before any input or output of data.. Or the scripts of malware disappears after execution... Or ... I never use my calender.. But I am always finding events.. scheduled at same time each day... events I cant access or remove them.. And thats just scratching the surface! Simona